Can I travel out of the Country with an Evidence of Visa Renewal Application
I am a Nigerian who is a postdoctoral fellow at the University of Johannesburg. My visa expired on 31st August; I have already applied for visa renewal in South Africa before the expiry date. Can I travel back to Nigeria with the Visa Application receipt? I need to book my Flight Ticket to travel back home in November.

You ask if you can "travel out of the Country" (in the title) and "travel back to Nigeria" (in the question text. As a Nigerian citizen with a valid passport, you will be able to exit South Africa. You can also enter Nigeria, although you may also have to deal with entry issues/visas for countries you will transit on your way to Nigeria. I suspect, however, that your actual question here is "Can I re-enter South Africa after my journey to Nigeria." Is that correct?

If you’re simply asking ‘can I exit S Africa’, then Yes. As a Nigerian citizen with a valid passport, you will be able to exit South Africa and enter Nigeria.
If you’re also asking ‘can I return to S Africa’, then according to this, the answer is also Yes. However, that page highlights several issues you may face along the way to be aware of.
